# Trying to put a video inside a svg, either with youtube or locally

Tags: html, css, svg, video

I'm trying to put a video as a mask in my svg. As if it's on a computer screen. I'm having some trouble doing it as when I run the code, the video isn't there.

```html
 <svg width="1146" height="655" viewBox="0 0 1146 655" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<mask id="mask0_5_448" style="mask-type:luminance" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="1" y="1" width="1160" height="653">
<path d="M1160.03 1.15997H1.01001V653.11H1160.03V1.15997Z" fill="white"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask0_5_448)">

 
      
<path d="M515.82 384.64C520.29 412.75 536.82 433.54 567.27 423.04C594.69 414.42 630.15 409.49 657.43 419.68C668.23 423.68 680.89 432.31 674.14 445.31C681.93 428.1 658.75 420.47 645.83 418.31C632.98 415.81 619.61 416.16 606.64 417.6C593.609 419.193 580.779 422.143 568.36 426.4C562.03 428.61 555.13 430.09 548.15 429.53C529.63 428.38 517.96 411.77 513.15 395.36C512.129 392.088 511.347 388.746 510.81 385.36C510.769 385.032 510.794 384.698 510.882 384.38C510.97 384.061 511.12 383.762 511.323 383.501C511.526 383.24 511.779 383.022 512.067 382.859C512.355 382.696 512.672 382.591 513 382.55C513.328 382.509 513.661 382.534 513.98 382.622C514.299 382.71 514.598 382.86 514.859 383.063C515.119 383.266 515.338 383.519 515.501 383.807C515.664 384.095 515.769 384.412 515.81 384.74L515.82 384.64Z" fill="transparent"/>
<path d="M68.44 645.22H85.6V1159.94C85.6 1160.56 85.3556 1161.15 84.9205 1161.58C84.4854 1162.02 83.8953 1162.26 83.28 1162.26H70.76C70.1447 1162.26 69.5546 1162.02 69.1195 1161.58C68.6844 1161.15 68.44 1160.56 68.44 1159.94V645.22Z" fill="#D4A163"/>
<path d="M980.81 654.34H-35L18.95 467.47H901.72L980.81 654.34Z" fill="#D4A163"/>
<path d="M654.23 606.14H179.02L220.56 530.55H612.69L654.23 606.14Z" fill="#E8F4FA"/>
<path d="M635.35 599.02H200.2L231.42 537.67H604.13L635.35 599.02Z" fill="#A0CDE7"/>
<path d="M611.4 578.34H222.68L238.7 546.12H596.75L611.4 578.34Z" fill="#D0E4EF"/>
<path d="M526.31 592.66H282.49L284.91 584.3H522.06L526.31 592.66Z" fill="#D0E4EF"/>
<path d="M619.03 592.66H531.91L527.32 584.3H617.52L619.03 592.66Z" fill="#D0E4EF"/>
<path d="M277.04 592.66H217.03L217.63 584.3H278.72L277.04 592.66Z" fill="#D0E4EF"/>
<path d="M470.01 297.58L368.88 297.03L342.22 510.62H494.83L470.01 297.58ZM376.56 396.43L379.46 376.68H458.46L461.35 396.43H376.56Z" fill="#A0CDE7"/>
<path d="M746.34 412.83C746.34 429.15 731.17 442.38 712.46 442.38H124.59C105.88 442.38 90.71 429.15 90.71 412.83V33.41C90.71 17.09 105.88 3.84998 124.59 3.84998H712.46C731.17 3.84998 746.34 17.09 746.34 33.41V412.83Z" fill="#D0E4EF"/>
<path d="M700.51 356.16C700.51 368.9 687.62 379.23 671.71 379.23H172.01C156.1 379.23 143.21 368.9 143.21 356.16V88.68C143.21 75.94 156.1 65.62 172.01 65.62H671.71C687.62 65.62 700.51 75.94 700.51 88.68V356.16Z" fill="none"/>



<path d="M700.51 356.16C700.51 368.9 687.62 379.23 671.71 379.23H172.01C156.1 379.23 143.21 368.9 143.21 356.16V87.3199C143.21 74.5799 156.1 64.2499 172.01 64.2499H671.71C687.62 64.2499 700.51 74.5799 700.51 87.3199V356.16Z" fill="none"/>



<mask mask-type="luminance" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="143" y="51" width="558" height="330">
  <rect x="143" y="51" width="558" height="330" fill="white" />
 
 
 <foreignObject x="143" y="51" width="558" height="330">

<iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pfznZ_cPxU0"></iframe>
  </foreignObject>


  <path d="M700.51 357.55C700.51 370.29 687.62 380.61 671.71 380.61H172.01C156.1 380.61 143.21 370.29 143.21 357.55V75.05C143.21 62.31 156.1 51.98 172.01 51.98H671.71C687.62 51.98 700.51 62.31 700.51 75.05V357.55Z" fill="#ff3030" />
 
</mask>



<g mask="url(#mask1_5_448)">
<rect x="134.48" y="65.65" width="571.2" height="323.2" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
</g>
<path d="M749.62 525.16C744.35 516.63 728.97 498.16 702.74 517.71C701.18 518.857 699.906 520.349 699.017 522.07C698.129 523.791 697.651 525.694 697.62 527.63C697.48 540.79 698.36 571.63 709.62 571.63C723.49 571.7 747.96 577.36 751.49 532.87C751.704 530.166 751.049 527.465 749.62 525.16Z" fill="#E8F4FA"/>
<path d="M726.67 509.09C727 529.433 725.051 549.75 720.86 569.66C720.604 559.495 721.005 549.323 722.06 539.21C722.956 529.082 724.495 519.022 726.67 509.09Z" fill="#A8CBE3"/>
<path d="M814.01 706.48L853.32 705.36L890.92 593.79L836.41 578.44C824.07 613.63 813.71 667.01 814.01 706.48Z" fill="#7B4B2A"/>
<path d="M685.76 560.62C679.85 569.96 694.16 579.97 700.21 585.74C705.015 590.201 710.228 594.202 715.78 597.69C719.56 600.116 723.557 602.185 727.72 603.87C738.34 657.87 788.94 712.55 788.94 712.55L854.25 676.6C854.25 676.6 799.72 673.97 756.25 598.39C756.329 598.287 756.384 598.167 756.41 598.04C756.485 598.017 756.554 597.977 756.611 597.924C756.669 597.87 756.713 597.804 756.74 597.73C758.33 593.04 760.66 588.55 761.23 583.73C761.72 579.66 760.03 575.96 757.97 572.51C754.89 567.36 751.59 562.69 749.69 557.04C748.658 553.743 747.892 550.369 747.4 546.95C747.16 545.5 747.4 543.27 746.4 541.95C743.4 538.42 735.88 542.36 734.07 545.59C732.14 548.99 732.82 552.04 734.07 555.27C735.43 558.75 736.99 562.04 738.24 565.47C736.222 563.074 733.956 560.899 731.48 558.98C726 554.53 722.67 549.85 718.99 544.39C715.31 538.93 712.52 533.5 709.19 528.08C707.37 525.14 703.95 522.08 699.4 521.98C696.45 521.89 695.2 525.22 695.15 526.87C695.131 527.925 695.235 528.979 695.46 530.01C689.95 531.25 689.71 537.82 690.36 542.79C685.14 544.21 683.82 551.63 684.28 555.67H684.22C684.642 557.28 685.18 558.858 685.83 560.39C685.78 560.456 685.755 560.537 685.76 560.62Z" fill="#7B4B2A"/>
<path d="M695.49 530.1C700.82 538.68 705.61 548.04 710.71 556.76C704.05 548.93 699.3 539.6 695.49 530.1Z" fill="#582815"/>
<path d="M690.39 542.88C693.56 549.3 696.25 556.38 700.98 561.83C694.98 557.74 691.81 549.83 690.39 542.88Z" fill="#582815"/>
<path d="M685.86 560.51C690.7 565.9 694.93 571.51 699.61 577.09C693.71 572.9 689.2 566.88 685.86 560.51Z" fill="#582815"/>
<path d="M818.25 604.41L923.57 622.16C923.57 622.16 944.82 448.56 937.95 447.95C907.45 445.24 824.13 502.55 818.25 604.41Z" fill="#FFCF35"/>
<mask id="mask2_5_448" style="mask-type:luminance" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="871" y="434" width="287" height="318">
<path d="M1157.62 469.99C1123.46 440.64 1096.99 434.44 1078.81 434.46C1072.44 434.46 1066.48 435.23 1047.54 435.95C1024.99 436.81 1006.6 436.73 994.54 436.53C983.37 440.74 960.09 448.05 939.38 448.45C886.72 449.45 868.44 649.45 871.38 733.45C959.73 761.89 1045.29 756.45 1148.84 717.67L1157.62 469.99Z" fill="white"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask2_5_448)">
<path d="M1157.62 469.99C1123.46 440.64 1096.99 434.44 1078.81 434.46C1072.44 434.46 1066.48 435.23 1047.54 435.95C1024.99 436.81 1006.6 436.73 994.54 436.53C983.37 440.74 960.09 448.05 939.38 448.45C886.72 449.45 868.44 649.45 871.38 733.45C959.73 761.89 1045.29 756.45 1148.84 717.67L1157.62 469.99Z" fill="#FFCF35"/>
</g>
<path d="M1230.4 823.93C1238.74 814.05 1227.84 796.77 1223.67 787.52C1220.42 780.482 1216.56 773.743 1212.13 767.38C1209.27 763.189 1206.02 759.278 1202.42 755.7C1207.58 684.06 1178.78 518.57 1178.78 518.57L1122.37 529.23C1122.37 529.23 1153.22 643.81 1173.42 753.34C1173.31 753.456 1173.23 753.588 1173.16 753.73C1173.07 753.742 1172.99 753.775 1172.92 753.825C1172.85 753.876 1172.8 753.943 1172.76 754.02C1169.9 759.43 1166.38 764.34 1164.47 770.18C1162.84 775.18 1163.47 780.38 1164.41 785.41C1165.91 792.92 1167.75 799.88 1167.96 807.64C1168.02 812.139 1167.79 816.638 1167.29 821.11C1167.11 823.03 1166.21 825.75 1166.86 827.71C1168.71 833.14 1177.08 830.6 1179.74 827.11C1182.56 823.45 1182.74 819.37 1182.48 814.89C1182.17 810.05 1181.61 805.39 1181.38 800.65C1182.6 804.252 1184.16 807.73 1186.03 811.04C1190.03 818.44 1191.89 825.43 1193.86 833.53C1195.86 841.42 1196.98 849.37 1198.64 857.29C1199.55 861.61 1201.98 866.52 1206.31 868.18C1209.11 869.25 1211.31 865.45 1211.78 863.38C1212.1 862.047 1212.3 860.688 1212.38 859.32C1218.02 859.53 1220.11 851.32 1220.91 844.83C1226.32 844.73 1229.71 835.83 1230.42 830.53H1230.48C1230.53 828.368 1230.47 826.205 1230.28 824.05C1230.33 824.019 1230.37 823.978 1230.4 823.93Z" fill="#7B4B2A"/>
<path d="M1215.21 605.39L1108.8 614.62C1108.8 614.62 1101.59 439.87 1108.48 439.82C1139.11 439.56 1217.54 503.39 1215.21 605.39Z" fill="#FFCF35"/>
<path d="M1025.38 473.95C1025.38 473.95 1095.67 535.27 1132.1 456.75C1132.1 456.75 1205.22 501.55 1196.84 411.2C1196.84 411.2 1288.59 436.69 1226.15 345.2C1226.15 345.2 1326.37 349.11 1196.15 245.39C1196.15 245.39 1258.08 259 1250.73 211.55C1243.38 164.1 1174.27 161.98 1174.27 161.98C1174.27 161.98 1230.73 168.98 1224.15 132.47C1217.57 95.96 1154.3 77.47 1093.42 92.74C1093.42 92.74 1171.56 81.22 1152.42 36.6C1133.28 -8.02004 1038.63 38.65 1038.63 38.65C1038.63 38.65 1077.23 -9.05004 1018.07 -11.87C958.91 -14.69 931.47 50.16 931.47 50.16C931.47 50.16 891.66 -4.08004 852.92 -0.840036C814.18 2.39996 835.5 37.87 835.5 37.87C835.5 37.87 769.76 24.57 750.41 61.92C731.06 99.27 792.9 139.87 792.9 139.87C792.9 139.87 741.64 107.51 707.11 127.94C672.58 148.37 671.11 184.45 739.11 199.63C739.11 199.63 669.35 213.33 666.87 274.49C666.44 285 672.98 296.25 705.93 295.92C705.93 295.92 595.85 409.81 720 413.03C720 413.03 702 540.23 834.88 468.87C834.88 468.87 837.97 637.05 942.88 495.71C943.01 495.76 1004.01 581.4 1025.38 473.95Z" fill="#2D1311"/>
</g>
<path d="M1160.03 1.15997H1.01001V653.11H1160.03V1.15997Z" stroke="#211C13" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0_5_448" transform="scale(0.00140056 0.00247525)"/>
</pattern>
<image id="image0_5_448" width="714" height="404" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAsoAAAGUCAYAAAAs+gRaAAAACXBIWXMAAA3XAAAN1wFCKJt4AAAgAElEQVR4XuzdeXxU5b0/8M8smSXrhLCEBCRhUSKgBEQRVCwIpWppiwaXurQXg9XeLlqDrfan1VbbBqvtba9todxrrVUvqLVWLBJBRQEVIShiQAgJS0jCkkz22c/vj8lMZjkzz5xklhPyeb9evCBzvjM5mTlhPvOc7/McjSRJ
</defs>
</svg>
```

took some of the image out for brevity, I'll attach the image as well. I'm trying to put a video in that screen [image]

Comment: yeah hard to put a mask when stack overflow wont let you upload svg, i'll take a screen shot

Comment: ok i can send you text there was text in my question

Comment: <mask id="mask1_5_448" mask-type="luminance" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="143" y="51" width="558" height="330">
 <foreignObject x="143" y="51" width="558" height="330">

    <iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pfznZ_cPxU0"></iframe>
  </foreignObject>
  
  <path d="M700.51 357.55C700.51 370.29 687.62 380.61 671.71 380.61H172.01C156.1 380.61 143.21 370.29 143.21 357.55V75.05C143.21 62.31 156.1 51.98 172.01 51.98H671.71C687.62 51.98 700.51 62.31 700.51 75.05V357.55Z" fill="#ffffff" />
 
</mask>

i use a mask here. doesn't seem to show up.

Comment: not quite sure why. it seems to do better on codepen.

Comment: https://codepen.io/audiophones_/pen/oNPQvQq

here it is on codepen

Comment: A video in a mask won't be interactive so you won't be able to play it. You'd need to just put the foreignObject in the main markup rather than putting it in a mask.